# Получить объект ячейки в TableView

Tags: java, javafx

В начале оперировал этой [статьей](http://www.naturalborncoder.com/java/javafx/2012/04/26/complete-javafx-2-editable-table-example/).

Но даже после этого есть проблема в том, что редактирование срабатывает только после двойного щелчка по ячейке. А хотелось бы по кнопке и сразу на нескольких (а не конкретно той, на которой тыкаем мышью).

Господа, выручайте! Как получить нужный `TableCell` из самой `TableView`?
Это бы упростило все в разы.

**UPD** Суть в том, что я переопределяю класс, который отвечает за отдельно взятые ячейки `TableCell`. А именно методы: `updateItem`, `cancelEdit`, `startEdit`.

Но проблема в том, что это лишь пол дела. Нужно как-то переопределить способ срабатывания этих методов. Т.к. по умолчанию они реагируют по двойному щелчку и только у конкретной ячейки.

Мне же нужно привязать срабатывание к отдельной кнопке и у ячеек всего ряда. (отключении тоже должно быть коллективным)

Comment: Распишите пожалуйста подробнее, что подразумевается под редактированием "по кнопке и сразу на нескольких".

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите, выбрав какую-то колонку и нажав определенную кнопку, редактировать сразу все ячейки в этой колонке?

Comment: @ Andrew Bystrov Столбце* Я кажется нашел способ. Он немного корявый, но работает. Постить пока не буду, вдруг у кого по адекватней способ.

Comment: Все таки запостите свой ответ, и возможно кто-то придумает, как его улучшить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге залезть в исходники оказалось продуктивней, нежели лезть в javadoc.

В отличии от строки и столбца, для ячейки нет отдельного метода. Его нужно получать через параметризованный запрос наследуемый аж от самого `Node`.

```
mainTable.queryAccessibleAttribute(
      AccessibleAttribute.CELL_AT_ROW_COLUMN,
      nomberRow, nomberColumn);
```